# Google Error Reporting not detecting errors logged by php application

Tags: php, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am having problems getting [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/) to work with errors being reported by my php applications running in a GCE instance.

I have followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setting-up-on-compute-engine) for setting up Google Error Reporting for my GCE instance.

I have confirmed that the messages are being logged to the Loggging page using the [required format](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages).

Here is one of the errors that are showing up in the Logging section of GCP

```
{
    metadata: {
        severity: "ERROR",
        projectId: <project_id>,
        serviceName: "compute.googleapis.com",
        zone: "us-central1-b",
        labels: {
            compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: <resource_name>,
            compute.googleapis.com/resource_type: "instance",
            compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: <resource_id>
        },
        timestamp: "2016-04-22T20:20:44.000Z",
        projectNumber: <project_number>,
    },
    insertId: <instert_id>,
    log: "alberta.errors",
    structPayload: {
        context: {
            reportLocation: {
                filePath: <path>,
                lineNumber: 22,
            }
        },
        serviceContext: {
            service: "alberta"
        },
        message: "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  password authentication failed ..."
    }
}
```

The Error Reporting page remains in the setup state:
[image: Error Reporting page in GCP]

I'm not sure where to go from here as I have exhausted the documentation available and haven't been able to find anyone with a similar issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our documentation seems to be incomplete, sorry about that! If there is no stack trace contained in the "message" field, we do require "functionName" to be set. We'll either update our documentation, or relax this requirement. To have your errors show up, please add a "functionName" property under "reportLocation" for now.

By the way, to quickly check whether a given JSON will show up in Error Reporting as expected, you can use the [gcloud](http://cloud.google.com/sdk/) command as follows (make sure to copy the complete JSON string):

```
gcloud beta logging write --payload-type=struct alberta.errors \
 '{"serviceContext": {"service": "alberta"},"message": "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  password authentication failed ...","context": {"reportLocation": {"filePath": "/some/path/to/a/file.txt", "lineNumber": 42, "functionName": "someFunction"}}}'
```